# how to convert a buffer to arrow parquet table in c++

Tags: c++, buffer, parquet

I read a parquet file from remote, so get the binary file, which is a buffer. (unsigned char *buffer) How can I convert it to readable table?

I can save the buffer to my local disk, for example

```
std::ofstream outFile;
outFile.open("../test.parquet", std::ios::binary);
for (int i = 0; i < file_size; i++)
{
    outFile << buffer[i];
}
```

Then read the parquet file to parse it. How can I convert the buffer to a readable table directly? I can use arrow::Buffer to store the buffer, but don't know how to parse it.

Comment: You'll need either a parquet file format library, or the parquet file format specification from which you can make your own parquet file format library.

Comment: All bytes are stored in the buffer, which is a complete parquet file. When I write the buffer to a local parquet file, then read it, I can parse the file. So the buffer contains all information.  But I don't want to dump the buffer to disk, then read it, but just parse it in the memory.

Comment: The "getting the bytes" logic (from file, from memory) should be separate from the "parsing the bytes" logic.

Comment: yes, I know. I read the file from remote store, so only get a buffer. But don't know how to parse it in memory. If write it to a local file, then use api to read it, I can achieve the goal. But I think the IO is unnecessary. There should be another api to parse it directly, right?

Comment: Again?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72240424/how-to-convert-a-buffer-to-arrow-parquet-table-in-c

Comment: I mean I want to parse the buffer to arrow table.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by self define RandomAccessFile

```
class VectorRandomAccessFile : public arrow::io::RandomAccessFile {
public:
  VectorRandomAccessFile(const std::vector<char>& data)
      : data_(data), position_(0) {
}
arrow::Result<int64_t> ReadAt(int64_t position, int64_t nbytes, void* out) {
    if(nbytes > 0) {
        memcpy(out, data_->data() + position, static_cast<size_t>(nbytes));
        position_ += nbytes;
    }
    return nbytes;
}
arrow::Result<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer>> ReadAt(int64_t position,
                                                int64_t nbytes) {
    return std::make_shared<arrow::Buffer>((const uint8_t*)data_.data() + position, nbytes);
}
arrow::Result<int64_t> Read(int64_t nbytes, void* out) {
    return ReadAt(position_, nbytes, out);
}
arrow::Result<std::shared_ptr<arrow::Buffer>> Read(int64_t nbytes) {
    return ReadAt(position_, nbytes);
}
arrow::Result<int64_t> GetSize() override {
    return data_.size();
}
arrow::Result<int64_t> Tell() const override {
    return position_;
}
arrow::Status Seek(int64_t position) override {
    position_ = position;
    return arrow::Status::OK();
}
arrow::Status Write(const void* data, int64_t nbytes) {
    // Not write
    return arrow::Status::OK();
}
arrow::Status Close() {
    is_close = true;
    return arrow::Status::OK();
}
void read();
bool closed() const override {
    return is_close;
}
private:
  bool is_close;
const std::vector<char>& data_;
int64_t position_;
};
```